# php send variable by input type submit

Tags: php

## Part of 'index.php'

```
<body>
    <?php include('form.php') ?>
    
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <select name="id"><?php playerID($tournament); ?></select>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php playerName($tournament); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Save Player">
    </form>
</body>
```

## Part of 'form.php'

```
function playerName($tournament) {
    $player = getPlayer($tournament);
    echo isset($player) ? $player->Name : '';
}
```

**This code works for me, but when I press on 'Save Player' to submit I can't send the $tournament to call function 'updatePlayer($tournament)'**

## Another part of 'form.php'

```
updatePlayer($tournament);

function updatePlayer($tournament) {       
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $player = $tournament->getPlayer($id);
        $player->Name = $_POST['name'];
        $player->Phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $player->Active = $_POST['active'];
    }
}
```

**I need something like this:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Save Player" <?php [SEND $tournament FROM HERE?] ?>>
```

Comment: I am sorry but to me it seems like you are used to using some kind of library but doesn't know how the language works. Your description is really confusing.

Comment: I'm new in php, and I'm trying to make it works...

Comment: I suggest to read some tutorials about forms in PHP.  Or about PHP in general.

Comment: The `$tournament` is saved in the `$_POST['name']`, just use that? You should read on basic form handling and basic PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your form on index.php needs to instantiate the function you have defined. To do this a simple $_POST detection at the top of the page will do. From there you can validate and run the function as intended.

```
if(isset($_POST['name')){
    //validation here???
    updatePlayer($_POST['name']);
}
```